# The code/command to determine/change the length/height ratio of scale bar?

Tags: dm-script

I would like to adjust the length/height ratio of the scale bar in an image by the DM scripting. As the following code shown, I can adjust the font size by changing "scalebar.componentsetfontinfo("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, fontsize)", but I do not know how to change the shape (length/height ratio) of rectangle which constitute to the scale bar. Is there any code/command can achieve this?  Thanks,

image front:=getfrontimage()

imagedisplay imgdisp=front.imagegetimagedisplay(0)

number nobar=imgdisp.componentcountchildrenoftype(31)

number fontsize=20

imgdisp.applydatabar(0)

component scalebar=imgdisp.componentgetnthchildoftype(31,0)

scalebar.componentsetfontinfo("Microsoft Sans Serif", 0, fontsize)

scalebar.componentsetdrawingmode(1)

Answer (score 1):

When you select a scalebar, you will notice the green points showing that component's rectangle.

[image]

You control that rectangle like you control any component rectangle:

```
number kScaleBar = 31
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
component scaleBar = disp.ComponentGetNthChildOfType( kScaleBar, 0 )
number t,l,b,r
scaleBar.ComponentGetRect(t,l,b,r)
Result("\n Current rect: [" + t + "/" + l + "/" + b + "/" + r )
number sx, sy
img.GetSize( sx, sy )
// Set centered half at bottom
l = sx*1/4
r = sx*3/4
t = sy*17/20
b = sy*19/20
scaleBar.ComponentSetRect(t,l,b,r)
```

Note, that you can not explicitly specify the length of the scalebar, it will always "snap" to a meaningful fraction within the boundary box, depending on the image calibration.
Setting the bounding rect will also override the font-size, while setting the font-size will override the boundary rect's height.